# Scroll View adding views on top of each other

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I can add several scrollviews with its background colours changed and it works fine. So basically for every view you have different background colours. However when I try to add separate views for each of these, it adds it right on top of the other and I don't know why.

```
UIViewController *view1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
UIViewController *view2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
UIViewController *view3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"];


for (NSInteger i=0; i<ScrollViewControllerNumberOfPages; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect subViewFrame = CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, pageHeight, pageWidth);
    NSLog(@"Printing Width and Height %f  %f",pageWidth,pageHeight);
    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subViewFrame];

    // Pick a random colour for the view
    CGFloat randomRed = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomGreen = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomBlue = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:randomRed green:randomGreen blue:randomBlue alpha:1];
    NSLog(@"printin i %i", i);
    if (i == 0)
    subView = view1.view;
    else if (i == 1)
        subView = view2.view;
[self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what are you trying to do, but when you do `subView = view1.view;` you make the `subView` pointer to point to the views loaded from the storyboard. Maybe you meant to do it the other way around, like `view1.view = subView`?

Comment: No. I want to add three different views one after the other in a scroll view

Comment: the first 10 or so lines of code in your for loop seem pointless since you set subView to be the view of the view controller afterwards though?

Comment: @wattson12 After the 2nd loop i isn't 0 or 1, so the subView setup above will be added to the scrollView.

Comment: Please don't put "URGENT" in the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a shot in the dark because your code would need some serious rethinking.

What you're doing is you allocate a `subview`, you modify it's frame and background and then completely disregard this and set it to a view of previously instantiated `viewcontoller`.

This should work (in a way):

```
UIViewController *view1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
UIViewController *view2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
UIViewController *view3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<ScrollViewControllerNumberOfPages; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect subViewFrame = CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, pageHeight, pageWidth);
    NSLog(@"Printing Width and Height %f  %f",pageWidth,pageHeight);

    UIView *subView;

    if (i == 0)
      subView = view1.view;
    else if (i == 1)
      subView = view2.view;

    subView.frame = subViewFrame;

    // Pick a random colour for the view
    CGFloat randomRed = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomGreen = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomBlue = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:randomRed green:randomGreen blue:randomBlue alpha:1];
    NSLog(@"printin i %d", i);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
}
```

It might look *a bit* better if you do it like:

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<ScrollViewControllerNumberOfPages; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect subViewFrame = CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, pageHeight, pageWidth);
    NSLog(@"Printing Width and Height %f  %f",pageWidth,pageHeight);

    UIViewController *subViewCont = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"View%d",i+1]];

    UIView *subView = subViewCont.view;

    subView.frame = subViewFrame;

    // Pick a random colour for the view
    CGFloat randomRed = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomGreen = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    CGFloat randomBlue = ((CGFloat)(arc4random() % 1000))/1000;
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:randomRed green:randomGreen blue:randomBlue alpha:1];
    NSLog(@"printin i %d", i);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
}
```

Comment: Your first code works. Now i am going to try the second piece. Thank you so much :)